# Is it possible to expand non-variadic arguments in a variadic template function?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

It is probably easier to explain what I mean by an example. Imagine a following template:

```cpp
template <class... Args>
std::tuple<Args...> foo();
```

It can be invoked, for example, like this:

```cpp
auto ret = foo<int, bool>();
```

But what if I want to pass additional arguments to the function, based on the number of variadic template arguments? For example, let's say I want to pass a character string literal for every Args:

```cpp
auto ret = foo<int, bool>("a", "b");
```

The problem with this, is that it does not seem possible to expand non-variadic arguments, so the following obviously doesn't compile:

```cpp
template <class... Args>
std::tuple<Args...> foo(const char*... names);
```

Is there any sensible way to implement this?

Comment: Take in a `std::tuple`?

Comment: There's no need for tuple in this case, because all types are of the same type. I could use initializer_list, but the question is specifically about an arguments.

Comment: You can still use variadic template, and than have a static assert to make sure those arguments are of the allowed types.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can do this with something like

```
template <class... Args>
std::tuple<Args...> foo(proxy<Args, const char*>... names);
```

where `proxy` is

```
template<class T, class E>
using proxy = E;
```

You can see this in action here: https://godbolt.org/g/SHBYzy

Comment: Very elegant solution.  No checks needed at all to make sure the list have the same amount of elements. +1