# Equal number of template and function params

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, variadic-templates

Is there a way to generate a templated function where there is an equal number of template params and function params (of the same type)?

Like the following:

```
// template function:
template<typename ... Args>
void foo(const std::string& a, const std::string& b, ...) { /*...*/}

// example 1
foo<int>("one argument only");

// example 2
foo<int, double>("first argument", "second argument");
```

What if there is a default function param (not templated) (or multiple) which always exists?

```
template<typename ... Args>
void foo(int i /* as default */, const std::string& a,
                                 const std::string& b, ...)
 { /*...*/}
```

Would it even be possible to have, let's say the duplicate number of function arguments (calculated by the size of the template params)?

Comment: Related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50450612/is-it-possible-to-expand-non-variadic-arguments-in-a-variadic-template-function

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is there a way to generate a templated function where there is an equal number of template params and function params (of the same type)?

Yes: it is (Edit: simplified following a Justin's suggestion; thanks!)

```
#include <string>

template <typename, typename T>
using skip_first = T;

template <typename ... Args>
void foo (skip_first<Args, std::string> ... as)
 { }

int main()
 {
   foo<int>("one argument only");

   foo<int, double>("first argument", "second argument");
 }
```

> What if there is a default function param (or multiple)?

```
template<typename ... Args>
void foo(int i /* as default */, const std::string& a,
                                 const std::string& b, ...)
 { /*...*/}
```

If you want one (or more) preceding parameter(s) of different type(s), yes it's possible.

```
template <typename ... Args>
void foo (int i, long j, skip_first<Args, std::string> ... as)
 { }
```

If you want a preceding parameter with a default value, no: isn't possible because a variadic list of parameter can't have a default value and because given a parameter with a default value all fallowing parameters have to have a default parameter.

> Would it even be possible to have, let's say the duplicate number of function arguments (calculated by the size of the template params)?

I suppose you can multiply (repeat the unpack more times) the unpack part

```
template <typename ... Args>
void foo (skip_first<Args, std::string> ... as1,
          skip_first<Args, std::string> ... as2)
 { }
```

Obviously this solution works only if you want multiply the number of template argument for an integer number.

Comment: You know, [`std::conditional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional) could be used instead of your custom `skip_first`.

Comment: `#include <iostream>` doesn't seem to be related to the solution??

Comment: @Deduplicator - I didn't think about it but... yes, works. I find a little more clearer the use of a specific type traits but the idea of use something standard is intriguing... uhmm

Comment: @AdrianW - you're right; debris of a preceding test; corrected; thanks.

Comment: Simplification: `template <typename, typename U> using skip_first_t = U;` and cut out the `skip_first` type.

Comment: @Justin - I've seen the `using` trick, to solve this sort of problems, four or five times but there is no  way to remember it; thanks.

Comment: @Felix - thanks to a Justin's suggestion, I've simplified my answer (`skip_first` become a trivial `using` instead of a `struct`)